# Java Iterator vs C# IEnumerable

Tags: c#, java, iterator

I've noticed that Java's `Iterator` (interface) is similar to C#'s `IEnumerable`, but is there any way to use it like this:

```
private IEnumerable<Label> it; 
it = labels.iterator();
```

In Java I could just do:

```
private Iterator<JLabel> it;
it = labels.iterator();
```

What's the C# equivalent of Java's `Iterator` interface?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It's not used very often, but the analogy is the [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) interface:

```
var enumerator = labels.GetEnumerator();
```

.NET's `IEnumerator` differs from Java's `Iterator` with the following:

- `Iterator` after construction is pointing at the first element of the collection (or, for an empty collection, is invalid and `hasNext` will return `false` immediately), `IEnumerator` points initially *before* the first element of the collection (for an empty collection `MoveNext` will return `false`)
- `Iterator` has `hasNext` method, while for `IEnumerator` you verify the result of `MoveNext` method
- `Iterator` has `next` method, while for `IEnumerator` you also use `MoveNext`
- `Iterator`'s `next` returns the next element, while with `IEnumerator` you use `Current` property after calling `MoveNext`
- `Iterator` in Java has `remove` method which allows you to remove elements from the underlying collection. There is no equivalent in `IEnumerator`

So for Java you'd iterate with something like this:

```
it = labels.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
{
    elem = it.next();
}
```

While in C#:

```
en = labels.GetEnumerator();
while (en.MoveNext())
{
    elem = en.Current;
}
```

Usually, having `labels` as a collection (which always implements [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)) you just use it directly:

```
foreach (var label in labels)
{
    //...
}
```

And of course, you can store `IEnumerable<T>` for later use (names referring to your example):

```
IEnumerable<Label> it = labels;
```

Beware, that `IEnumerable<T>` is lazy, just like `Iterator` in Java.

You can also easily obtain a snapshot of a collection like this (again, `it` refers to your example, better name could be chosen):

```
IEnumerable<Label> it = labels.ToArray();
// or Label[] it = labels.ToArray();
// or better: var it = labels.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

There is another difference between Java's iterator and .Net's IEnumerable. The former has a `previous()`method which the latter lacks.